# How to install .c and Makefile drivers on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, makefile, arduino

I am a newbie.
I am trying to install CH340 drivers on Ubuntu 14.04 and I don't know where to start. this is a driver for arduino clone
The folder has a Makefile and ch34x.c.
I tried to compile the ch34x.c with GCC and got an error.

```
~/Downloads/CH341SER_LINUX$ gcc -o driver ch34x.c
ch34x.c:20:24: fatal error: linux/init.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/init.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
```

when running make in the directory i get:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.11/build  M=/home/mko/Downloads/CH341SER_LINUX  
make: *** /lib/modules/3.8.11/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

documentation info:

```
Instructions

Note: 1.Please run followed executable programs as root privilege
      2.Current Driver support versions of linux kernel range from 2.6.25 to 3.9.10
      3.Current Driver support 32bits and 64bits linux systems

Usage:
    (load or unload linux driver of CH34x)
    //compile 
    #make
    //load ch34x chips driver
    #make load
    //unload ch34x chips driver
    #make unload
```

I checked my kernel version using "uname -r" and got 3.8.11

Comment: I did, i updated the text.

Comment: Do you have that directory? Does that directory match your kernel? Does this module come with any documentation?

Comment: it has a readme file but is very short. it says "2.Current Driver support versions of linux kernel range from 2.6.25 to 3.13.x" but my kerel is 3.8.x..any way to make it work?

Comment: That's within the range so that should work. Does that directory exist? Do you just need to install the kernel development headers?

Comment: no there is no build folder in /lib/modules/3.8.11 I updated the question again with some documentation info. it might help

Comment: What version of ubuntu is this? From the website it looks like 12.04 shipped with a 3.11.0 kernel (or at least ended on that kernel).

Comment: this is Trusty (i think 14.04) with XFCE

Comment: How do you have a 3.8.11 kernel on trusty? What does `uname -a` output?

Comment: Linux localhost 3.8.11 #1 SMP Mon Jul 13 22:34:31 PDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  ....btw i am running this on a chromebook using crouton. I specified trusty and XFCE

Comment: maybe it fails because I need a build directory. How can I get that

Comment: Ah, so some odd build of ubuntu then most likely. I would expect one of the kernel/linux header/devel packages to provide it but I don't know. You could try just creating it manually but that may not be a good idea.

Comment: how should I install those packages

Comment: I don't know which package it would be offhand. I tried looking but didn't find it easily and I don't do kernel development to know how this is supposed to work. You could try looking for more general kernel/module development documentation to see if it says.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a crouton-specific issue. Here's the apparent fix:

First you will need to have support for https, it isn't installed by default when creating a chroot with crouton. So install the following package.

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

Now you need to add my public key because I signed the packages. Do that with the following command.

```
wget -O - "https://raw.github.com/divx118/crouton-packages/master/mauricevankruchten@gmail.com.gpg.key" | sudo apt-key add -
```

Adding the apt repo to your sources.list

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line in the file.

```
deb https://raw.github.com/divx118/crouton-packages/master/ saucy main
```

Then you should be able to run these commands to fix the headers

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo umount /lib/modules/3.8.11
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.8.11
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.8.11
```

Note: that I only tested it on saucy for now. This should work for the HP chromebook 14, Acer C720 and the Dell 11.

SOURCE:
 https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/772#issuecomment-40894248

Answer (score 0):

The code has been updated. I had the same errors.
There is a better version [here](http://www.wch.cn/downfile/177).
Check line 18 of the readme file :

```
// 1.2 - 1.3 Fix some bugs
```

The source I used was dated `12Sep2015 09:30`, also use the `new Makefile` and `make clean` first.

Answer (score -1):

You have to read the readme.txt, it states, that you actually perform the commands as root.

```
#sudo make
#sudo make load
```